# How to take distinct value in SQLite joined table?

Tags: android, sqlite, join, distinct

```
query = "SELECT" +
            " e.id AS _id," +
            " ke.id AS ke_id," +
            " ke.fk as ke_fk," +
            " ke.value as ke_value," +
            " re.id AS ke_id," +
            " re.fk as re_fk," +
            " re.value as re_value," +
            " s.id AS  s_id," +
            " s.fk as s_fk," +
            " g.id AS g_id," +
            " g.fk as g_fk," +
            " g.lang," +
            " g.value as g_value" +
            " FROM entry e" +
            "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk" +
            " WHERE g.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%' LIMIT 20";
```

I have table 'gloss'. I has column in 'value'. It is 'g_value' in joined table. For example, when I search "girl", it found out five duplicated results.

[image]

How to take distinct value of 'g_value' in order to avoid duplication in result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Union of rows if specific column value is dublicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172174/union-of-rows-if-specific-column-value-is-dublicated)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to eliminate the duplicates by using GROUP BY.  Like this:

```
query = "SELECT" +
            " e.id AS _id," +
            " ke.id AS ke_id," +
            " ke.fk as ke_fk," +
            " ke.value as ke_value," +
            " re.id AS ke_id," +
            " re.fk as re_fk," +
            " re.value as re_value," +
            " s.id AS  s_id," +
            " s.fk as s_fk," +
            " g.id AS g_id," +
            " g.fk as g_fk," +
            " g.lang," +
            " g.value as g_value" +
            " FROM entry e" +
            "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk" +
            " WHERE g.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%' " +
            " GROUP BY " +
            " LIMIT 20";
```