# Union of rows if specific column value is duplicated

Tags: android, sqlite, join

For example I have 3 tables:

> table1(id,value) table2(id,fk,value) table3(id,fk,value)

table2 and table3 are children of table1.

I have following SQL query:

```
query = "SELECT" +
            " t1.id AS _id," +
            " t2.id AS t2_id," +
            " t2.fk as t2_fk," +
            " t2.value as t2_value," +
            " t3.id AS t3_id," +
            " t3.fk as t3_fk," +
            " t3.value as t3_value," +
            " FROM t1 table1" +
            "     INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.fk" +
            " WHERE t2.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%' LIMIT 10";
```

Cursor is giving following result:

[image]

How to make like this:

[image]

My intention is to avoid duplication of values and at the same time collect all t3_value in one place. How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = "SELECT" +
            " t1.id AS _id," +
            " t2.id AS t2_id," +
            " t2.fk as t2_fk," +
            " t2.value as t2_value," +
            " GROUP_CONCAT(t3.value) as t3_value," +
            " FROM t1 table1" +
            "     INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.fk" +
            " WHERE t2.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%'
            GROUP BY t1.id, t2.id, t2.fk, t2.value  LIMIT 10 ";
```

and understand that what you want is "GROUP_CONCAT(X,Y)" - partial reference [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT e.id AS _id, ke.id AS ke_id, ke.fk as ke_fk, GROUP_CONCAT(ke.value) as ke_value, re.id AS ke_id, re.fk as re_fk, re.value as re_value, s.id AS  s_id, s.fk as s_fk, g.id AS g_id, g.fk as g_fk, g.lang, g.value as g_value FROM entry e     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk WHERE g.value like '%g%' LIMIT 20 GROUP BY e.id, g.id, g.fk, g.value

Comment: @JoeRichard yes, put the limit at the end. apologies - updated